# Spring Batch - Resume already started job when master fails

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, spring-batch

I didn't find an answer to my question so far so I'm giving it a try here.

Let's assume a Spring Batch application with remote partitioning. There's one master/manager application partitioning the dataset and sending it to Kafka (to multiple partitions) and worker nodes are consuming from different Kafka partitions to run in parallel. So far so good.

The question is, what happens if while the workers are still processing the data and doing their own things, the manager application suddenly crashes.

The obvious answer is that the partitioning job execution will stay as `STARTED` even though the respective worker jobs have the state `COMPLETED`.

How can I restart the master node without doing the partitioning again and triggering the workers? The only thing I'd want in this case is to mark that particular job execution as `COMPLETED` since all the worker steps have completed.

I tried restarting the job with the `JobOperator` interface but obviously it fails since the job is in `STARTED` state and not in `FAILED`.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.batch.core.UnexpectedJobExecutionException: Illegal state (only happens on a race condition): job execution already running with name=partitioningJob and parameters={}
```

Any suggestions are welcome.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can change the status of the job execution from `STARTED` to `FAILED` and set its `END_TIME` to a non `null` value before restarting the same job instance (you might need to do that for the step execution as well if needed). On restart, the manager should notice that all workers have completed and will complete the execution.

Comment: Hi Mahmoud, nice to have you here. :) You mean manually doing an SQL update or is there an easier API to use (like a Repository or something)? Btw is this something on the Spring Batch roadmap? Generally speaking, is there any doc/suggestions on failure handling both on the master and worker side? Sorry for the long comment. :)

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I meant changing the status manually in the db as mentioned in the appendix here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/job.html#aborting-a-job. You can do it programmatically if you manage to detect the failure of the manager. There is no plan to automate this in Spring Batch as this is a business decision (mark the job as failed and restart it or abandon it). The rule of thumb when a partitioned job fails (either the manager of one of the workers) is to restart the same job instance: only failed partitions should be reprocessed.

Comment: Thanks Mahmoud. I have another one for you. What happens when the workers are still processing the partitions while the manager is restarted? Still the manager should move the partitioning job status to FAILED and then restart the job? In that case the manager will still wait until the workers complete all their partitions?

Comment: In that case, the manager should wait until all workers finish their partitions (successfully or with a failure) up to a configurable timeout.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't want to sound ignorant, just wanna make sure I understand it. So in the case I described above (workers are still processing but the manager got restarted), I still need to transition the job state to FAILED and restart the batch job with a JobOperator even though the workers are still processing. This will instruct Spring Batch to restart the job (since it failed) but since the workers are still processing, it's just going to wait until all of them are done. (?)

Comment: No worries, happy to help. Yes, this is the expected behaviour in that case.

Comment: Okay, makes sense. Thanks Mahmoud. I don't want to push too much stuff on you but I had a related question and appreciate some feedback: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71693901/spring-batch-restart-behavior-upon-worker-crash

Comment: Mahmoud, do you mind pointing me to this part of the codebase where the manager is able to detect that the partitions have completed so the "partitioning" job has to be updated only instead of executing a brand new partitioning step? I'm trying to get this together but what's happening for me is that all the step executions are complete except the partitioning step. I change the status for the job execution to failed and restart the same exact job with the JobOperator but it executes a brand new job with all the partitions again.

Comment: Also, I have an example project for this if you wanna see the exact implementation. What's the best way to discuss this in more detail? Gitter/Twitter/?

Comment: The code should be here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/b7d144c10d43e18b06f7921d751f97e21ab4a9a7/spring-batch-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/core/job/SimpleStepHandler.java#L201. If you restart the same job instance (ie with same job parameters), only failed partitions should be replayed, not all of them. If you share a minimal complete example on Github, I can try to take a look.

Comment: My mistake Mahmoud, the thing is, I didn't know when I set the job execution to FAILED I also need to set the start_time and end_time to null otherwise Spring Batch will think that the job is still running. Works as expected. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear you resolved that issue! It is actually my mistake, my answer should have been more precise about what to set for that to work. Setting the end_time to a non null value should be enough (the start time should be already set when the job started). I updated the answer accordingly. If that helped, please accept the answer.

Comment: The thing is, the code has this line in SimpleJobRepository#126 where it's checking if the job is still running and it checks if `startTime != null && endTime == null` which means I have to set both to null. When the job hangs, the start time is already set but the end time is null so it will be considered as running. Am I missing something?