# Spring Batch - restart behavior upon worker crash

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-batch

I've been exploring how Spring Batch works in certain failure cases when remote partitioning is used.

Let's say I have 3 worker nodes and 1 manager node. The manager node creates 30 partitions that the workers can pick up. The messaging layer is Kafka.
The workers are up, waiting for work to arrive on the specific topic. The manager node creates the partitions, puts them into the DB and sends the messages on the Kafka topic which has 3 partitions.

All nodes have started the processing but suddenly one node has crashed. The node that has crashed will have the step execution states set to STARTED/STARTING for the partitions it initially has picked up.
Another node will come to the rescue since the Kafka partitions will get revoked and reassigned, so one of the nodes between the 2 will read the partition the crashed node did.
In this case, nothing will happen of course because the original Kafka offset was committed by the crashed node even though the processing hasn't finished. Let's say when partitions get reassigned, I set the consumer back to the topic's beginning - for the partitions it manages.
Awesome, this way the consumer will start consuming messages from the partition of the crashed node.

And here's the catch. Even though some of the step executions that the crashed node processed with COMPLETED state, the new node that took over will reprocess that particular step execution once more even though it was finished before by the crashed node.
This seems strange to me.

Maybe I'm trying to solve this the wrong way, not sure but I appreciate any suggestions how to make the workers fault-tolerant for crashes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a `StepExecution` is marked as `COMPLETED` in the job repository, it will not be reprocessed. No data will be run again. A new `StepExecution` may be created (I don't have the code in front of me right now) but when Spring Batch evaluates what to do based on the previous run, it won't process it again. That's a key feature of how Spring Batch's partitioning works. You can send the workers 100 messages to process each partition, but it will only actually get processed once due to the synchronization in the job repository. If you are seeing other behavior, we would need more information (details from your job repository and configuration specifics).

Comment: Hi Michael, I'll do some more testing and get back to you because this was my expectation as well.

Comment: Michael, I'm actually seeing a different behavior and I'm sure it's not something with Spring Batch itself (since you know the functionality better than anyone) but some misconfiguration or misusage. What I actually see is that the workers reprocess already completed partitions. I can also share an example. Is there a better way to communicate on this than in a SO comment? Gitter maybe or smthing?

Comment: If you restart the same job instance (ie with same job parameters), only failed partitions should be re-executed, not all of them. If you share a minimal complete example on Github, I can try to take a look.